# Add new partition to CentOS file system

Tags: partitioning, centos, filesystems, vmware-workstation

I use a CentOS virtual machine on VMWare Workstation. I recently tried to increase the system hard disk memory for CentOS by tweaking the VM settings on VMWare Workstation. After that, I tried to follow the steps as listed here:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1006371

However, when I try to list the Volume Groups using **vgdisplay**, it shows that there are no Volume Groups. How do I resolve this issue?

terminal on typing vgdisplay:

> Incorrect metadata area header checksum on /dev/sda4 at offset 4096
>
> No volume groups found

The new partition to be added is /dev/sda4

terminal on typing fdisk -l :

> Disk /dev/sda: 128.8 GB, 128849018880 bytes
>
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15665 cylinders
>
> Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x0007bec8
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/sda1   *           1          39      307200   83  Linux
>
> Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
>
> /dev/sda2              39        2354    18598912   83  Linux
>
> /dev/sda3            2354        2611     2064384   82  Linux swap / Solaris
>
> /dev/sda4            2611       15665   104857592+  8e  Linux LVM

I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Please help.